# Raster Format Exception

Tags: java, exception, sprite

I've been trying to create a sprite for our game but the problem is when i tried to run the program this error appears

```
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.image.RasterFormatException: (y + height) is outside of Raster
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.createWritableChild(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(Unknown Source)
at really.sprite.TrueSprite.<init>(TrueSprite.java:31)
at really.sprite.Sprite.main(Sprite.java:13)
```

here's the program that causes the error:

```
public class TrueSprite
{
BufferedImage spriteSheet = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/robin.png"));

int width = 240, height = 314, rows = 5 , columns = 5;

BufferedImage[] sprites = new BufferedImage[rows * columns];

public TrueSprite(int width, int height, int rows, int columns) throws IOException
{
this.width = width;
this.height = height;
this.rows = rows;
this.columns = columns;

for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
    {
        sprites[(i * columns) + j ] = spriteSheet.getSubimage(i * width, j * height, width, height);
    }
}

}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
g.drawImage(sprites[1], 314, 240, null);
}


}
```

the image size I imported is 1200 x 1570.

Comment: What does `spriteSheet.getWidth` and `spriteSheet.getHeight` print?

Comment: height is 1570 and width is 1200